# getting class name of check box when it checked only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, each

i have any html code which contains two check boxes and having class names like this

```
<p class="text">
                <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="ques11" name="radiobutton" class="option_1" />
                <label for="ques11">True</label>
                <span class="hide" id="ans1">Answer: True</span>
                <span id="rite11" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_correct.png"/></span>
                <span id="wrong11" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_wrong.png"/></span> </p>

            <p class="text">
                <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="ques12" name="radiobutton" class="option_2" />
                <label for="ques12">False</label>
                <span id="rite12" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_correct.png"/></span>
                <span id="wrong12" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_wrong.png"/></span> </p>
```

i have written script to get which chekbox is checked

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
  var quesNo = this).closest("div[id^='questionsNo_']").attr('id').split('_');
 var chapterId = quesNo[1]; 
 var questionId = quesNo[2];
 var optionId = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
 ...
```

in var optionId  i want to get the checked one  like,if i checked the 1st check box ,i want to get '1' value from 'option_1' ,suppose i have checked second check box ,i want to get 2 from 'option_2'.how to get the value of checked checkbox only .

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check in for the psuedo selector `:checked`, more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
   var quesNo = $(this).closest("div[id^='questionsNo_']").attr('id').split('_');
   var chapterId = quesNo[1]; 
   var questionId = quesNo[2];
   var optionId;
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      optionId = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
   } else {
      //Else don't set it or do something else for this case
   }
});
```

alternatively if all you want is information on the checked field just include this in your original selector before you loop, for instance....

```
var selectedNum = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('class').split('_')[1]
```

Please note the above won't work if the selector returns multiple results, in that case you'll need to loop or choose the one you want to get.

**UPDATE**

If you want a json just create the variable as an object and set it's value as the number from the class like so

```
var myJSON = { 'option_id': $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('class').split('_')[1] };
```

Bearing in mind that you'd need to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) this object for it to be a true JSON.

Comment: { "option_id":"2"}

Comment: @memoriesforever Did you manage to get this working, please accept or upvote my answer if you found it useful or let me know if not so that others can benefit from this as well.....